# In django 1.6.5 what should be FORMAT_MODULE_PATH for TIME_ZONE='Asia/Kolkata'

Tags: python, django, localization, date-format

my django project in v. 1.6.5 has several applications. The directory structure on linux is as follows:

```
/home/abc/myproject/
                   mysite/
                   __init__.py 
                   locales/
                   mysite/
                          settings.py  
                          __init__.py 
                          en/
                          __init__.py
                          formats.py
```

`formats.py` contains formats for date:

```
DATE_FORMAT = '%d/%m/%Y'
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%d/%m/%Y', '%d-%m-%Y', '%d-%m-%Y')
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

`settings.py` contains settings:

```
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = 'myproject.locales'



$ locale
LANG=en_IN
LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
LC_CTYPE="en_IN"
LC_NUMERIC="en_IN"
LC_TIME="en_IN"
LC_COLLATE="en_IN"
LC_MONETARY="en_IN"
LC_MESSAGES="en_IN"
LC_PAPER="en_IN"
LC_NAME="en_IN"
LC_ADDRESS="en_IN"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_IN"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_IN"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_IN"
LC_ALL=
```

I want my project to use `dd/mm/yyyy` format for all applications. What else needs to be done to make this effective? Indian time

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I want my project to use dd/mm/yyyy format for all applications"? 
Do you want to save IST in database or display IST everywhere on your website?

Comment: display IST everywhere on your website http://stackoverflow.com/users/1134517/dhiraj-thakur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by creating a module called formats in my project directory and importing it in the other applications:

```
/home/abc/myproject/
                   mysite/
                         application1/
                         formats/
                         __init__.py
                         /en_IN/
                               /formats.py
                               __init__.py
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right you are missing the `__init__.py` in your `locales` folder.